# Where is Voice Recorder in Nokia 8?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, microphone, voice-recording, nokia-8

I really want to know where is Voice Recorder in [Nokia 8](https://www.nokia.com/en_ke/phones/nokia-8). If there isn't any Voice Recorder App in Nokia 8, is there an application on the play store which can work specifically for the Nokia 8 unique microphone setup and utilize the Nokia 8 three microphone array?

Comment: See the [topic in Nokia Support forums](https://community.phones.nokia.com/support/discussions/topics/7000010719)